# Add tomcat listener LifecycleListener without changing server.xml or tomcat/web.xml

Tags: java, tomcat

I have below code which required below entry in server.xml and file must placed in tomcat/lib.

I want to add tomcat listener and ***do not want*** to make any changes in **tomcat server configuration**. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Note : I have already tried "ServletContextListener" but it is not accurate as LifecycleListener.

Server.xml

```
<Listener className="com.tomcat.listener.TomcatListener"/>
```

Java file

```
package com.tomcat.listener;

import org.apache.catalina.Lifecycle;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleEvent;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleListener;

public class TomcatListener implements LifecycleListener {
    @Override
    public void lifecycleEvent(LifecycleEvent event) {
        if(Lifecycle.AFTER_START_EVENT.equals(event.getType())){
            System.out.print("Tomcat successfully started");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With the help of `ServletContextListener`, `LifecycleListener` and reflection I am able to achieve what I was expecting.

So here we are first capturing event of `ServletContextListener` to get the `ServletContext` and then using reflection and we are accessing private fields to add listener in `ServletContext` implementation of Tomcat

CustomServletListener.java

```
import org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext;
import org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade;
import org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public final class CustomServletListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        addLifeCycleListener(event);
    }

    /**
     * Tomcat Implementation of ServletContext in ApplicationContextFacade, ApplicationContext,StandardContext as to addListener is located in StandardContext 
     * @param event
     */
    private void addLifeCycleListener(ServletContextEvent event) {
        ApplicationContextFacade source = (ApplicationContextFacade) event.getSource();
        ApplicationContext objApplicationContext=get(source, "context");
        StandardContext objStandardContext = get(objApplicationContext, "context");
        objStandardContext.addLifecycleListener(new TomcatListener());
    }

    /**
     * Get class field using reflection as it is no way to direct access
     * @param object
     * @param fieldName
     * @param <V>
     * @return
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <V> V get(Object object, String fieldName) {
        Class<?> clazz = object.getClass();
        Field field = null;
        boolean wasAccessible = false;
        while (clazz != null) {
            try {
                field = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
                wasAccessible = field.isAccessible();
                if (!wasAccessible) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                }
                return (V) field.get(object);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            } finally {
                // Revert the Accessibility flag to previous state
                if(null != field && field.isAccessible() != wasAccessible){
                    field.setAccessible(wasAccessible); 
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

TomcatListener.java

```
import org.apache.catalina.Lifecycle;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleEvent;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleListener;

public class TomcatListener implements LifecycleListener {
    @Override
    public void lifecycleEvent(LifecycleEvent event) {
        if (Lifecycle.AFTER_START_EVENT.equals(event.getType())) {
            System.out.print("Tomcat successfully started");
        }
    }
}
```